# Html Drawing on canvas gets resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to simply create a canvas that has a grid with cell sizes of 20 by 20 px.
The canvas is nested within a div with scrollbars.

I've got this dot grid function for a canvas that I got from [here](https://codepen.io/veljamatic/pen/pypxRR)

```
$(function () {


        function getDocumentWidth() {
            return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        };

        function getDocumentHeight() {
            return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
        };

        var canvas = document.getElementById('can1');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var vw = getDocumentWidth(),
            vh = getDocumentHeight();

        // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
        window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
        function onResize() {
            vw = getDocumentWidth();
            vh = getDocumentHeight();
            resizeCanvas();
        }

        function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = vw;
            canvas.height = vh;
            drawDots();
        }
        resizeCanvas();


        // grid
        function drawGrid() {
            var cellW = 20,
                cellH = 20;

            // vertical lines
            for (var x = 0; x <= vw; x += cellW) {
                context.moveTo(x, 0); // x, y
                context.lineTo(x, vh);
            }

            // horizontal lines
            for (var y = 0; y <= vh; y += cellH) {
                context.moveTo(0, y); // x, y
                context.lineTo(vw, y);
            }

            context.strokeStyle = "#cccccc";
            context.stroke();
        }
        // drawGrid();

        // dots
        function drawDots() {
            var r = 1,
                cw = 20,
                ch = 20;

            for (var x = 20; x < vw; x += cw) {
                for (var y = 20; y < vh; y += ch) {
                    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
                    context.fillRect(x - r / 2, y - r / 2, r, r);
                }
            }
        }
        drawDots();


    })
```

And here is how the canvas is placed in html:

```
<div class="forCanvas" >
        <canvas id="can1" class="dropZone ui-widget-header" width=581 height=821 >
        </canvas>
</div>
```

and all the css:

```
.dropZone {
   width: 581px;
   height: 821px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background: #fff;
}

.forCanvas {
   height: 600px;
   width: 680px;
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The problem is that the size of these cells is not 20 by 20 and the drawing gets resized when changing the browsers dimensions.

From what I understand its a problem with view port width and height vs actual width and height? So I tried setting the width and height as such:(seen above also)

```
<canvas id="can1" class="dropZone ui-widget-header" width=581 height=821 >
```

I previously used this function with the same problem:

```
function drawGrid() {
    var cellW = 20,
        cellH = 20;

    // vertical lines
    for (var x = 0; x <= vw; x += cellW) {
        context.moveTo(x, 0); // x, y
        context.lineTo(x, vh);
    }

    // horizontal lines
    for (var y = 0; y <= vh; y += cellH) {
        context.moveTo(0, y); // x, y
        context.lineTo(vw, y);
    }

    context.strokeStyle = "#cccccc";
    context.stroke();
}
```

**ALSO HERE ARE PICTURES TO SHOW YOU HOW IT LOOKS:**

BEFORE RESIZING
[image]

AFTER RESIZING

[image]

Any help or explanation would be much appreciated. **Thank you!**

**EDIT**

Here is a full code to test out the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<style>
    .dropZone {
        width: 581px;
        height: 821px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: #fff;
    }

</style>




</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="can1" class="dropZone ui-widget-header" width=581 height=821 >
    </canvas>
    <script>
        function getDocumentWidth() {
            return Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        };

        function getDocumentHeight() {
            return Math.min(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
        };

        var canvas = document.getElementById('can1');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
        function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = getDocumentWidth();
            canvas.height = getDocumentHeight();
            drawDots();
        }

        function drawDots() {
            var r = 1;

            for (var x = 20; x < canvas.width; x += 20) {
                for (var y = 20; y < canvas.height; y += 20) {
                    context.fillRect(x - r / 2, y - r / 2, r, r);
                }
            }
        }

        resizeCanvas();
    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Interesting... what browser do you use?

Comment: @HelderSepu Well by default the project opens on Chrome, but I just tested this on edge and firefox and the same problem occurs.

Comment: Do you have a link to your project? if you don't have one can you create it on github? I tried to reproduce it but it was working fine for me.

Comment: Here is my attempt to reproduce your problem: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvasResize.html

Comment: Wow, this is weird... I added a sample that when used gives me the same exact problem... what you have on githack is exactly what I need, what did you change from the codes that I posted in the questions? @HelderSepu

Comment: Here is my code: https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/master/HTML/canvasResize.html

Comment: Thank you for your Help, I figured out  thanks to you what was causing the problem: setting up the width and height. Simply removing them from the css removed the problem... But I need to set the dimensions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I added the canvas inside a div with the dimensions I wanted. (The problem was caused by setting dimensions to the canvas).

As such:

```
<div  id="can2" class="dropZone ui-widget-header">
            <canvas id="can1"></canvas>
</div>
```